# jquery bind event to one checkbox in array of checkboxes

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, bind, checkbox

I have a dynamic group of checkboxes pr_network_ids that is a HABTM relationship in RAILS.  So they each have the same name, but different values

I want to toggle a div to be shown or hidden when pr_network_ids_2 and pr_network_ids_4 is clicked/unclicked.

Using JQuery i have tried to access it using ("#pr_network_ids_2").click, but i can't get it to work.  Is there a way to access a specific checkbox using the id or name or get the entire array of checkboxes and bind an event to the ones if there value equals 2 or 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("input:checkbox[name=nameOfTheCheckbox]").each(function(){
       var $this = $(this);
 if($this.val() == "2" || $this.val() == "4"){
  //bind the events here
  $this.bind("click", function(){ });
 }
});
```

Comment: $j("input:checkbox[name=pr_network_ids_]").each(function () {   var  $this = $j(this);   if($this.val()==2) { $this.bind("clicl", function() { if($this.is(":checked")) { $j("#siteDiv").show("fast"); } else {$j("siteDiv").hide("fast");  but nothing happens when I click the checkbox

Comment: Your code has issue the click spelling is incorrect. Also make sure the name of the input checkboxes is correct.

Comment: The click is spelled correctly in my code.  It's on a different system so I have to retype it manually here.  The checkboxes on my form look like this: <input id="pr_network_ids_" name="pr[network_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="2"/>  So what should i put in the jquery name=pr_network_ids_ or name=pr[network_ids][] ??

Comment: First of all why is it rendering as pr[network_ids][]? Try with this $('input:checkbox[name="pr[network_ids][]"]')

Comment: That's how rails displays it's relationships on the views.  I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

If you use $("#pr_network_ids_2") you have to find the checkbox, if you have defined the checkbox with that id.

example

```
<input type="checkbox" id="pr_network_ids_2" value="lalala" />
```

Make sure Your checkbox has the correct ID.

Answer (score 0):

`("#pr_network_ids_2").click(...)` should work.  But if they are dynamic, you either need to do the binding after they are created or use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: using the .live() function would i tie it to ("pr_network_ids_2") or the parent "#pr_network_ids and then look for the value of 2?

Comment: Either way will work, depending on what you want to do.  If you are asking for a general feature across all your `pr_network_ids` then you would do the latter, but if each `pr_network_ids` does it own special thing, then it would be better to go with the former.